# Char(1) vs tinyint(1) - bool

Tags: mysql, sql, database, char, boolean

In MySQL, bool data type is essentially same as tinyint(1).

My question is what is exact difference between char(1) and tinyint(1)? I know you store character in char and store number in tinyint, but is there any significant diffrence between them? The byte sizes are same so I want to know the actual difference between them.

Also, what is the maximum display width in SQL data type? I saw that is not constraining the actual range of int then what is it actually constraining?

Thank you!

Comment: `tinyint` has values like 0, 1, 2, 3.  `char(1) has values like `'A'`, `'Z'`, and `'!'`.  That seems like a pretty significant difference.  Use the one that does what you want.

Comment: 'what is it actually constraining' - display size https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html

Comment: Don't forget that `tinyint(1)` can still store a value like `42`

Comment: also if you are using an ORM or DB library, a boolean type might assume a tinyint (or an integer type).  So you can use native boolean values in the ORM which are translated to 0 or 1 when communicating with the DB.  ```Customer.where(active: true)``` <-- assumes an integer value when using MySQL

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  if that's the case, for boolean should I use tinyint(1) or char(1)?

Comment: @xor . . . In MySQL, `boolean` is a synonym for `tinyint`.  You don't have to worry about this; the database takes care of that decision for you.